# How to cross-fade videos?

Tags: windows, video-editing

I need a tool that allowed me to make smooth transitions between videos. Windows Movie Maker doesn't allow that as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use AviSynth (but that is not interactive, programmer oriented). Anyway, Movie Maker allows fading, I believe.

Comment: Since you posted here I'm learning AviSynth. It's seems a bit difficult to crossfade. I think I will have to: 1) Cut both clips in 2 pieces, 2) fade one piece of each clip, 3) layer the faded pieces together and 4) concatenate the 3 resulting clips.

Comment: Do you know where can I find AviSynth help forums? Doom9 requires 5 days of registration before posting.

Comment: It's more simple, look the Dissolve function http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Dissolve

Answer (score 1):

You can do cross-fades with Windows Movie Maker.

In timeline mode drag the following clip onto the previous clip to make a cross-fade between them. The further you drag it the smoother the transition is.

Comment: It seems very limited and counter intuitive in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

In [Adobe After Effects CS5](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) it's pretty easy.

1. Put video 1 in a layer of your composition
2. Put video 2 in a layer below that
3. Expand video 1 layer details
4. Click in the stopwatch symbol right next the Opacity setting
5. Set the opacity to 100% for a given point in time
6. Select another point in time
7. Set the opacity to 0%

You can do the same to audio. Use 0 db instead of 100% and -40db instead of 0%